# Angular 2 components gets loaded before route is resolved

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

The component's ngOninit is getting hit before the getReport service returns data.It doesn't wait for the service to be resolved.

routing:

```
 @Injectable()
class ReportResolver implements Resolve<any> {
constructor(private reportsService: ReportsService) {
}
resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
): any {
    this.reportsService.GetReport(route.params["id"]).subscribe((data: any) => {
        return data;
    });
}}

const appRoutes: Routes = [
{
    path: "reports/:id",
    component: TabularReportsFachadeComponent,
    resolve: { report: ReportResolver }
},
{
    path: "",
    component: DashboardComponent
},];
```

service:

```
GetReport(id: any): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.get("api/reports/?" + id).map(res => res.json());
}
```

component:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    debugger
    this.report = this.route.snapshot.data["report"].data;

}
```

the components ngOninit is getting hit before the getReport

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`resolve` should return an `Observable`, not a `Subscription`. Actually your `resolve` doesn't return anything, but you should not call `subscribe()` on the `Observable` because this returns a `Subscription`.

If you need to process the value before returning, use `map((val) => ...)` or some other operator instead.

```
resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
): any {
    return this.reportsService.GetReport(route.params["id"])
}}
```

Comment: Glad to hear :) Thanks for the feedback.